# How to write a Linux command in a Dockerfile

Tags: linux, dockerfile

I have a linux shell command, that need to be written in a Dockerfile.

```
for ((i=10001; i<10101; ++i)); do pwgen -n -s -B -c 10 | sed "s/^/$i /"; done > user.tx_ ; /bin/cp -f user.tx_ user.txt ;
```

Anybody can help me ? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `RUN` keyword in order to execute stuff.
If it's shell command you want to run, you can run `bash -c` with your shecl script.

See some examples and doc here:. 
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#run

Comment: All right.Actually I need the Dockfile codes.I have tried many times.

Answer (score 0):

This can provide you with a shell inside the container:

```
docker exec dockernamehere bash
```